# Pruning of backup files as they get older

Tags: backup, files, time, logrotate

I'm looking for a tool (for Linux) that will prune my backup files, not like the standard `logrotate` that completely deletes them after defined number of rotations, but where the files are basically kept permanently, except they are pruned as they get older and older. For example:

- for the first month I want to keep every single daily backup file
- after that I only want to keep a weekly backup for the next 6 months
- after that I only want to keep a monthly backup for another 6 months
- after that I only want to keep a quarterly backup

Does a tool to do such a time-based cleanup of files exist?

It could either be looking at a date in the file name, or the timestamp of the file (not ideal though).

Comment: This seems like a pretty basic thing for any backup software to handle transparently. How are you generating these backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a tool I know of, usually this is inculded in your backup software. What backup tool do you use?

I would recommend [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/)
This can be configured to do these smart things you ask for, and keeps backup size small by extensive use of hardlinks.

If however you have your own cronjobs/system for creating backups, you could just create a few more [cronjobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

- make backups to a 'daily folder'
- have a weekly cronjob that moves files older then 30days from your monthly folder to your 'weekly folder' `find /path/to/daily -maxdepth 1 -mtime +30 -type f -exec mv "{}" /path/to/weekly/ \;`

  because the below cronjob will remove older files this will only be one day's worth of backup files.
- have a daily cronjob that removes files older then 30 days from your daily folder (make sure it runs after the weekly cron above) `find /path/to/daily/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;`

repeat for weekly to monthly and monthly to quarterly

Comment: Sneaky solution. It's only solid though if the cron job runs every day - it can't do it after-the-fact. But that could be okay.

Comment: @theStoryCoder yes it does work after the fact, find will return all files older then 30 days if you use -mtime +30; you can manualy run it once if you want to cleanup now.You might have to play with the amount of days...

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather old, but since it's the first result for this type of search, I would recommend [Borg](https://www.borgbackup.org/) as your backup option, as it supports exactly the kind of backup schedule you're looking for via its [Prune](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/prune.html) command.

From one of the examples in their documentation:

```
# Use the `prune` subcommand to maintain 7 daily, 4 weekly and 6 monthly
# archives of THIS machine. The '{hostname}-' prefix is very important to
# limit prune's operation to this machine's archives and not apply to
# other machines' archives also:

borg prune                      \
--list                          \
--prefix '{hostname}-'          \
--show-rc                       \
--keep-daily    7               \
--keep-weekly   4               \
--keep-monthly  6               \
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the "duplicacy" software, too.

It has very good reputation; and (independently) I am using it, and I am satisifed.

Comment: Payware though.

Comment: Not if you are using the CLI version on Linux

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem I had and could not find a solution for. I was generating a lot of backup files gzip'ing configs on my servers. I ended up coding a solution.

https://github.com/BinaryPatrick/Prune

It uses the same pruning logic as [Proxmox's backup server](https://pbs.proxmox.com/docs/prune-simulator/), and runs in the command line. I compiled it for linux-x64 with the following command and then I run it on the server from a cron job.

```
dotnet publish --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained -p:PublishSingleFile=true -c Release -o ./out/linux-x64
```

```bash
prune --path /mnt/backup/images --ext img --keep-last 3 --keep-daily 3 --keep-weekly 2 --keep-monthly 2
```